# How to determine when the cmd.exe is finished

Tags: c#, windows, cmd

I have some code that I found [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?381405-Automate-Command-Prompt-Window-(CMD)-Redirect-Output-to-Application-2003-2005).  It traps the output from cmd.exe and also sends input to it.  I am using it (heavily modified) on a form in our application.  It works well so we can hide cmd.exe from the users but allow this form to administrators.  Other benefits include a favorites list, ect.

Here is some code.  Note: I deleted 70% of the code to simplify it so there may be issues.  If anyone wishes to run this code and they are having problems let me know and I will edit it and make sure it works.  All it needs is a form with two textboxes, txtConsoleIn and txtConsoleOut plus a timer; tmrSelectedCommand.

```
public partial class frmCommandPrompt : Form
{
    private bool CancelOutput;
    private bool FirstTime = true;
    private bool InternalCommand;
    private string InternalCommandResponse;
    private ProcessStartInfo psi;
    private Process p;
    private string SelectedCommand;
    private bool SelectedCommandExecuteNow;

    private delegate void InvokeWithString(string text);

    public frmCommandPrompt()
    {
            InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmCommandPrompt_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.txtConsoleIn.Select();

    }

    private void tmrSelectedCommand_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmrSelectedCommand.Enabled = false;
        if (SelectedCommand != string.Empty)
        {
            if (SelectedCommandExecuteNow)
            {
                ExecuteCommand(SelectedCommand);
            }
            else
            {
                txtConsoleIn.Text = SelectedCommand;
                txtConsoleIn.SelectionStart = txtConsoleIn.Text.Length;
                txtConsoleIn.Select();
            }
            SelectedCommand = string.Empty;
            SelectedCommandExecuteNow = false;
        }

    }

    // Sending console commands
    private void txtConsoleIn_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        string Command;

        if ((int)e.KeyCode == (int)Keys.Return)
        {
            InternalCommand = false;
            Command = txtConsoleIn.Text;
            ExecuteCommand(Command);
            txtConsoleIn.Clear();
        }
    }

    private void Async_Data_Received(Object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.IsHandleCreated)
        {
            this.Invoke(new InvokeWithString(Sync_Output), e.Data);
        }
    }

    private void Sync_Output(string text)
    {
        if (!InternalCommand)
        {
            if (!CancelOutput)
            {
                OutputText(text);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (text != String.Empty)
            {
                InternalCommandResponse = text;
                InternalCommand = false;
            }
        }

    }

    private void ExecuteRecentCommand(string Command, bool ExecuteNow)
    {
        SelectedCommand = Command;
        SelectedCommandExecuteNow = ExecuteNow;
        tmrSelectedCommand.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void ExecuteCommand(string Command)
    {
        CancelOutput = false;
        p.StandardInput.WriteLine(Command);
    }

    private void OutputText(string text)
    {
        txtConsoleOut.AppendText(text + Environment.NewLine);
        txtConsoleOut.ScrollToCaret();
    }


}
```

I would like to display the path, like prompt=$P$G.  I can issue the command echo %cd% and trap the output while suppressing both that command and output.  I
can then output this and add a ">."  So far so good.  Now the problem.

Sometimes commands can change the path.  So I need to check the path again, but when?  What if someone enters a long running command?  How do I know when it is done?  I would prefer to make this work as closely to the original cmd.exe as possible for ease of use.

is cd the only command that changes the path (besides a poorly written batch file)?  If so I can check the path after that command.  But I will have to use a label since a command like dir *.txt /s issued from the root can take some time and it will not only look stupid to throw the path in the middle of that output but will make the form less useable than not even displaying the path at all.

Or maybe have a timer starting another instance of cmd.exe running every 20 seconds or so just to get the path and display it in a label.  Sounds like a lot of wasted cycles for little gain.

At this point the best bet seems to force the users to check the path themselves.  I can add a button to get the path to make it easier but I would prefer a nicer solution.

Comment: ``p.WaitForExit();`` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You just don't know, the prompt is not reliable and you can't know if cmd.exe waits for the command to finish or not.  Type-ahead is not reliable if the started command also accepts input.  This needs to work the way it does when you run cmd.exe normally, interactively.  The user simply waits for the program to finish and only types ahead if he know that is safe to do.

Comment: @Hans, that's what I was afraid of.  Thanks for verifying it.

Comment: Why do you need a wrapper program like this?  If I understand rightly, you're launching `cmd` from the wrapper program anyway, presumably with the console window hidden; why not launch it with the console window visible instead and let the admin interact with it in the usual way?  (Incidentally, in most situations the security benefits of blocking direct user access to the command line are minimal.)